# Proving complex inequality

Tags: inequality, complex-numbers, absolute-value, triangle-inequality

I am struggling to prove the following complex inequality:

$\left | z+4 \right |-2\leq \left | z+2 \right |, \text {where} \:z \in \mathbb{C} $

My thought process so far is to use the triangle inequality for complex numbers:

$\\\left | z_{1}+z_{2} \right |\leq \left | z_{1} \right |+\left | z_{2} \right |, \text {where} \:z_{1}, z_{2} \in \mathbb{C}$

And that gives:

$\\\left | z + 4 \right |\leq \left | z \right |+\ 4\\\left | z + 4 \right |-2\leq \left | z \right | +2\geq \left | z+2 \right |$

But i seem to be stuck here and help would be appreciated

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Observe that:
$$|z+4| = |(z+2)+2| \leq |z+2|+2$$

by the triangle inequality.